# Use an un-initialized pointer as a function parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

As I want to pass an uninitialized pointer to a function, it goes runtime error.
but if I pass this pointer as a reference, it works OK. I cannot explain why...

```
class Body
{

};

void check(Body* b)
{
    b = new Body();
}

void checkRef(Body* &b)
{
    b = new Body();
}

int main001()
{
    Body* b;

    //check(b);// error: The variable 'b' is being used without being initialized. (in VS2010)
    checkRef(b); // OK


    return 0;
}
```

Whats the difference when b is passed to check and checkRef? I get the runtime error in VisualStudio2010. error:The variable 'b' is being used without being initialized.

EDIT: it was a VS2010 debug output. the "error" doesn't appear in release version

Comment: Are you sure the first one gives you a *runtime* error, and not a *compile-time* error?  What is the error message that you get?

Comment: Your life would be much easier if check() returned the pointer.

Comment: I am sure.  in VS2010, @"The variable 'b' is being used without being initialized."

Comment: I don't think it should give any runtime error. `check results in a memory leak but should not be runtime error`. Well the difference is CheckRef will result into a memory allocation whose pointer will be with b inside main. In other case, when check returns, b will still be dangling.

Comment: @demaxSH: It's almost certainly _not_ a runtime error, though it could be output from your debugger. A little screenshot would clear this up, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Tomalak: Excuse me, it was not actually an runtime error, it was a debugger output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Body * &b` b is an alias of/reference to the `b` in `main` - so when you assign to it you modify the `b` in `main`. In `Body* b` b is a *local copy of* the `b` in `main`, you're modifying this local copy and not the `b` in `main`.

Your runtime error is likely due to using the uninitialized `b` in `main`.

EDIT: The actual error you get is an extra check-for-typical-problems mechanism embedded into your code by your compiler. It detects that you pass something uninitialized by value, which doesn't make sense, and therefore generates this error.

If you disable this behavior, the application will appear to function properly until you try to dereference the uninitialized `b` in `main`

Comment: @demaxSH: The error you get is because the compiler generates code to check for such problems - You're passing something uninitialized by value, and that doesn't make sense in any way so a compiler-generated check produces this error. If you built a "Release" build with such extra checks disabled, you wouldn't get this error, you'd see the symptoms of it later in the application when trying to use the uninitialized `b`

Comment: Yes I didn't get runtime errors when compiled in gcc. I didn't realize the "new" initializer will modify the pointer, well now I know

Comment: @demaxSH: it's not the `new` that modifies the pointer, it's the assignment to the pointer. Assignment will always modify the object being assigned; that is its purpose.

Answer (score 8):

In order to be equivalent to the `checkRef` version, your `check` function should read:

```
void check(Body** b)
{
    *b = new Body();
}
```

and called as

```
check(&b);
```

If you don't pass the address, as you do in `check(b)`, then you are passing the current *value* of the pointer `b` which is indeed uninitialised.

Comment: Indeed. It's important to remember that "uninitialised" is _more_ than just "doesn't point to anything sensible", or "points to an arbitrary place in memory". Using it uninitialised is **invalid** (strictly, UB)... whatever "using" means.

Answer (score 3):

`Body* b` does not set b to point to anything sensible. So it may point to some random location which could cause the earth to shift a bit.

Passing it to check(by value for the pointer) does not make it initialised in any way

```
void check(Body* b)
{
    b = new Body();
}
```

If you passed it by pointer to pointer, it should be okay

```
  void check(Body** b)
  {
     *b = new Body();
  }
```

And the call

```
check(&b);
```

Better done in C++ way with the reference example you give since that updates the referenced pointer value to point to the newly allocated Body

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're seeing a *run-time* error; at most I would expect to receive a *compile-time* warning/error.  But you can probably fix it by initialising `b` to `NULL` (but this won't fix your program; see below...)

The difference between the first and the second function call is that the first one will cause a memory-leak.  You are passing the pointer *by-value*, so inside `check()` you are working with a copy of that pointer.  You assign this copy, but this doesn't affect the value of the pointer in `main()`, so when you leave the function, there is no way to access the memory that was obtained by `new`.